# Install Redis on Alpine based image in docker

Tags: docker, go, redis, alpine-linux

I am trying to install Redis on the `golang:1.10.1-alpine3.7` image. I tried `RUN apk add --no-cache redis`, but when I tried to run the `redis-cli` command, I get an exit status 127, which means the given command in not found. I would like to know how I would be able to run the `redis-cli` command.

Comment: I've just tried building the container like you instructed and when executing `redis-cli` the command seems to run just fine. Perhaps try using the fully qualified path of the command - `/usr/bin/redis-cli`

Comment: Do you mind sharing a snippet of your code?

Comment: Thanks i got it to work with `/usr/bin/redis-cli`.

Comment: Cool, I'm adding that as an answer and would appreciate it if you could mark it as answered for anyone else who will seek an answer to this question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using the fully qualified path of the command - `/usr/bin/redis-cli`.

Answer (score 33):

To install it , use command as

```
apk --update add redis
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the version of alpina in the Dockerfile

```
From alpina:3.8
RUN apk add --update redis
CMD [ "redis-server" ]
```

It works fine with version 3.8
and when it use version 3.19 it doesn't work.
https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main: temporary error (try again later)